# Simplest way to send messages between Matlab, VB6 and VB.NET programs

Tags: vb.net, vb6, matlab, message, interprocess

We are upgrading a suite of data acquisition and analysis routines from VB6 programs to a mixture of VB.NET, VB6, and Matlab programs.  We want to keep the system modular (separate EXEs) so we can easily create specialized stand-alone analysis programs without having to constantly upgrade one massive application.  We have used MBInterProcess to send messages between EXEs when all the programs were written in VB6 and this worked perfectly for us (e.g., to have the data acquisition EXE send the latest file name to a stand-alone data display program). Unfortunately, this ActiveX cannot be used within Matlab or VB.NET to receive messages.  We are wondering what is the simplest string message passing system (pipes, registered messages, etc) that we could adopt. Right now we are just polling to see if new file was written in a specific folder, which can't be the best solution. Our ideal solution would not require a huge investment in time learning nuances of Windows (we are biologists, not full-time programmers) and would work in both WinXP and 64-bit versions of Windows.

In response to the queries, we have wrapped the entire Matlab session within a VB6 program that has the MBInterProcess ActiveX control.  That works but is not a great solution for us since it will probably lock us into WinXP forever (and certainly will prevent us from using the 64-bit version of Matlab). The latest version of Matlab (2009a) can access .NET functions directly, so we assume one solution might be to use the .NET library to implement pipes (or something similar) across programs.  We would like to recreate the elegantly simple syntax of the MBInterProcess ActiveX and have a piece of code that listens for a message with that program's top-level Windows name, and then call a specific Matlab m-file, or VB.NET function, with the string data (e.g., file name) as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create an ActiveX EXE in VB6 to simply forward messages between the different parties? When anyone called it, it would raise an event with the parameters passed to the call. Your VB6 and VB.NET code could establish a reference to the ActiveX exe to call it and sink its events. I'm not familiar with Matlab so I don't know whether it would be accessible there.

EDIT: you've written that Matlab 2009a can access .NET directly. If it can sink .NET events, you could also have a .NET wrapper on the VB6 ActiveX EXE.

Here's some sample code I knocked up quickly.

VB6 ActiveX EXE project with project name VB6MatlabMessenger. Each message has a text string Destination (that somehow identifies the intended recipient) and a string with the message.

```
'MultiUse class VB6Messenger
Option Explicit

Public Event MessageReceived(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)

Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)
  Call Manager.RaiseEvents(Destination, Message)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Call Manager.AddMessenger(Me)
End Sub

Friend Sub RaiseTheEvent(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)
  RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Destination, Message)
End Sub

'BAS module called Manager
Option Explicit

Private colMessengers As New Collection

Sub AddMessenger(obj As VB6Messenger)
  colMessengers.Add obj
End Sub

Sub RaiseEvents(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)
  Dim obj As VB6Messenger
  For Each obj In colMessengers
    Call obj.RaiseTheEvent(Destination, Message)
  Next obj
End Sub
```

And a test VB6 normal exe, with a reference to the VB6MatlabMessenger. Here is the whole frm file. Build this as an exe, run a few copies. Fill in the destination and message text fields and click the button - you will see that the messages are received in **all** the exes (reported in the listboxes).

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.Form Form1 
   Caption         =   "Form1"
   ClientHeight    =   3090
   ClientLeft      =   60
   ClientTop       =   450
   ClientWidth     =   4680
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   ScaleHeight     =   3090
   ScaleWidth      =   4680
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows Default
   Begin VB.ListBox lstEvents 
      Height          =   1620
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   3
      Top             =   1320
      Width           =   4455
   End
   Begin VB.TextBox txtMessage 
      Height          =   375
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   2
      Text            =   "Message"
      Top             =   840
      Width           =   2295
   End
   Begin VB.TextBox txtDestination 
      Height          =   375
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   1
      Text            =   "Destination"
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   2295
   End
   Begin VB.CommandButton cmdSendMessage 
      Caption         =   "Send Message"
      Height          =   495
      Left            =   2640
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   360
      Width           =   1575
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Form1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objMessenger As VB6MatlabMessenger.VB6Messenger

Private Sub cmdSendMessage_Click()
  objMessenger.SendMessage txtDestination, txtMessage.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Set objMessenger = New VB6MatlabMessenger.VB6Messenger
End Sub

Private Sub objMessenger_MessageReceived(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)
  lstEvents.AddItem Now() & " RECEIVED - " & Destination & ", " & Message
End Sub
```

I started writing a VB.NET class library that wraps the VB6 to make it accessible to .NET. I haven't tested this one. It has a reference to the VB6MatLabMessenger.

```
Public Class VBNETMatlabMessenger
  Private WithEvents objVB6Messenger As VB6MatlabMessenger.VB6Messenger

  Public Event MessageReceived(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)

  Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String)
    objVB6Messenger.SendMessage(Destination, Message)
  End Sub

  Public Sub New()
    objVB6Messenger = New VB6MatlabMessenger.VB6Messenger
  End Sub

  Private Sub objVB6Messenger_MessageReceived(ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Message As String) Handles objVB6Messenger.MessageReceived
    RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Destination, Message)
  End Sub
End Class
```

This might get you started. Note that the VB6 messenger objects will live forever because the messenger keeps a reference to them internally, so COM will never tidy them up. If this becomes a problem (if **many** messages are sent without rebooting the PC) you could add a method to the VB6 messenger which instructs it to removed the messenger object from its collection,

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Matlab dos command to execute a Java program on the commandline, it waits for the commandline to complete before returning control to Matlab. This worked fine for me, after my Matlab program regained control I read the output file from the Java.

I've used compiled Matlab programs (i.e. exe's), these work okay but they spray files around when they execute - I believe it's possible to pass in commandline arguments to a compiled executable. Assuming VB.NET is like C# .NET you could execute your exe from code using something like the Process object.

Alternatively there are ways to compile to .dll which are accessible via .NET see here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/matlabeng.aspx

for an explanation. I've never tried this...

Comment: Looks like the DDE and COM suggestions in the article you've linked would also work with VB6.

Comment: That's my understanding - I must admit that I've steered clear of such things for fear of banging head against mysterious compiler incantations.