# C# and Matlab 2010. Real-time events

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I need to send some text information from C# to Matlab 2010. And then send some response from matlab to C# app.

I have very little knowledge of Matlab so I will try no to get involved in the Matlab part of the solution but I have to establish communications.

**Can a matlab program listen to .NET app events? 
Can a matlab program then call a method in .NET app?**

**What is the general idea of deployment** of such solution? I.e. is it .NET app calls a managed dll compiled by Matlab Builder or is it Matlab loads a .NET dll and host it inside Matlab run-time?

Appreciate tolerance to the lame questions in advance :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Simplest way to send messages between Matlab, VB6 and VB.NET programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872469/simplest-way-to-send-messages-between-matlab-vb6-and-vb-net-programs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to compile the Matlab Program to a .NET or COM component with the [Matlab Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.de/products/netbuilder/description1.html) ([documentation, needs an matlab account](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dotnetbuilder/)) and just use the component from your program.

Some examples: [link](http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/toolbox/dotnetbuilder/ug/bp_dn5y.html)